Change style path in a server environment
When Angular app is developed locally, background CSS style has a value of /assets/banner.png as shown here:
.classname {
     background-image: url(/assets/banner.png);
}

When the app is deployed, the correct path in a server environment is
 background-image: url(/server/assets/banner.png);

How do I instruct Angular to prepend the image paths with /server?
Right now, I am doing a bunch of sed statements on the index.html file, which works. Figured there is probably a better way than just seding everything.

How's this getting generated? If it's in SASS stylesheet, have you tried specifying a relative path to the image?

use background-image: url(./assets/banner.png); or background-image: url(assets/banner.png);. See that if you prepend with '/' Angular search in "your-dominio.com" and not take account the "base href"

@amphetamachine this is a hardcoded path to image in regular css file. Using relative path background-image: url(./assets/banner.png); results in compilation error.

@Eliseo using relative path results in Angular compilation error.

@sanjihan, I made a little stackblitz and looks like work :(

@Eliseo Thanks for commenting. I found the problem. I my environment url(/assets/banner.png) works. url(assets/banner.png) or url(./assets/banner.png) is a compilation error. I figured I need to prepend the path with src as in url(src/assets/banner.png).  Now it works.  url(./src/assets/banner.png) is a compilation error as well. Thank you all.

@Eliseo I was too fast.. While url(src/assets/banner.png) does compile, it results in the incorrect path on the server.

In angular.json you can configure the assets, see link. The "input" (where you have the "assets" (can be in different folders), and the "output" (where all the assets are creating). By defect it's create in a folder assets in the same directory your index.html is. This is the reason to use "relative" paths

I know this might seem like overkill, but it could be useful for other purposes, such as setting up environments that you plan to use. Having done this several times, I've created a simple script to help you with it. I am also guessing you want to dynamically generate the envs as well.
This script can generate the necessary envs, and you can run it during the build process.
Below are the steps to achieve this

Create a generate-environment.js, script


const { writeFile } = require('fs');

require('dotenv').config();

const isProduction = process.env['DEPLOYMENT_ENV'] === 'prod';
const assetBaseUrl = isProduction ? '/server' : '';

const environmentFileContent = `
export const environment = {
   production: ${isProduction},
   assetBaseUrl: "${assetBaseUrl}"
};
`;

writeFile('./src/environments/environment.ts', environmentFileContent, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Environment file created successfully.');
    }
});


Update your Angular component and makes sure your Angular components use the updated environment

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  backgroundImageUrl: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.backgroundImageUrl = `${environment.assetBaseUrl}/assets/banner.png`;
  }
}


How your html file would look like

<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + backgroundImageUrl + ')'}">
  <!-- Your content here -->
</div>


Add this to your package.json file.

"scripts": {
  "prebuild": "node generate-environment.js",
  "build": "ng build"
}

By following these steps, you ensure that the environment configuration is dynamically generated and used correctly in your Angular application during the build process.

I feel that it's more simple: not prepend with / the url

Hi @Eliseo I agree with you, I wanted to suggest this but the asker had a specific question that was why provided the answer

@DerekRoberts Thanks for the suggestion. This would definitively work.
